# How to fix Error: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, dart

I know, this question has already been asked, but there they always talk about something callec "bloc" and I have no idea what this is and I don't use it in my app. Anyways, since the latest update of flutter, I get this error `Error: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.` and I don't know how to solve it. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: The deprecation warning should suggest using [`findAncestorStateOfType`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findAncestorStateOfType.html) instead.  Also see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/69620 and https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-0-fe8e95ecc65 for a list of other breaking changes.

Comment: Thank you, @jamesdlin , this actually solved it.